# find max number in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, max

this is my code in matlab

```
n1=input('Please enter a number:');
n2=input('Please enter a number:');
n3=input('Please enter a number:');
n4=input('Please enter a number:');
n5=input('Please enter a number:');
function max = mymax(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
max=n1
if n2>max
    max=n2;
end
if n3>max
    max=n3;
end
if n4>max
    max=n4;
end
if n5>max
    max=n5;
end



mymax(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)


fprintf('The maximum number is:%d\n ',max)
end
```

i create the function to find the maximum number between five numbers but i can not print the max number when i run the code i enter five numbers but then my program ends and it does not show me the out put in fact i do not know how should i show the max number

Comment: The call to `mymax` should be outside of the function definition. Still, the builtin function `max` can already do what you want...

Comment: Call `mymax` on line 6, before the `function` def. Assuming this is some assignment where the in-built `max` isn't permitted, you should still not overwrite the built-in `max` as a variable and use a unique variable name

Comment: If you realise a much simpler way, is just to use `1 for loop and an array` with all your values to find the max.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is just using the built-in max function.

You can make a new matrix with your inputs by:

```
mat = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]
```

Then, to get the max of that matrix just use:

```
nmax = max(mat)
```

Finally, to get the max value to print, use:

```
fprintf('The maximum number is: %d\n', nmax)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code ends at line 5 without executing the function after it.
Furthermore, your code has a bug that is doing infinite recursive. So you have to remove the call

> mymax

in the function.

your code should be fixed like this one:

```
n1=input('Please enter a number:');
n2=input('Please enter a number:');
n3=input('Please enter a number:');
n4=input('Please enter a number:');
n5=input('Please enter a number:');

mymax(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)

function max = mymax(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5)
max=n1;
if n2>max
    max=n2;
end
if n3>max
    max=n3;
end
if n4>max
    max=n4;
end
if n5>max
    max=n5;
end    
fprintf('The maximum number is:%d\n ',max)
end
```